Replace print() output in terminal, for long strings
I have a function in python that the user can run, which can be exit by sending ctrl-c. I want to display a timer on this function, to show how long it was running for, followed by a few static messages. My current implementation of this involves a combination of \033[A, \033[K and \r characters. Already works in normal cases.
My issue is that these characters tell the terminal how many physical lines to move up. In case the update string is multiple lines long (suppose they minimized or split panes in tmux) this will cause issues. Is there any way to count the length of the printed strings? I can use os module to get width of terminal, but don't know how to convert that into lines (preferably for a general string which may contain any ascii characters.
I already looked at curses but this seems geared towards applications needing to rewrite the whole terminal screen. I just want to append to any previous history the terminal might have had.
P.S. I would highly prefer to keep external dependencies as limited as possible. I mean to use this code easily on any containers. Standard Library is of course available.

As you say, os.get_terminal_size() would return the size of the terminal in columns and lines. Given that the number representing the 'columns' means how many characters can fit in a line, (e.g., columns = 80 would mean max. 80 characters per line) you can calculate how many actual lines a string is occupying if you take its length.

Note that if you want to count the number of lines taken by a print, indeed, just measure the length of what you are about to print, and divide by the width of your terminal, and keep track of position of each printed line. But if you want to be able to do so even if the terminal is resized (which your question seems to indicate), then that is near impossible. Because there is no standardization about what a terminal is supposed to do with existing content when it is resized. So you can't predict what size are the lines when the terminal has been resized.

Some terminals (that is software that emulate a physical terminal: you talk to then by sending them chars to "print", one after the other, some of those chars being control chars, like the \033[ sequences. A terminal being itself a physical device that emulate a printer, back from the time when print literaly meant "print". So, we still inherit from the times when, when something was printed, it was printed, on paper, and don't need to be cared about anymore); so some terminals, store the whole flow they were sent, printable chars and control chars, and just rerender everything

something along: int( len(THE-STRING) / list(os.get_terminal_size())[0] ) + (len(THE-STRING)+ 1 > 0 )) should give the minimum number of lines reqd

in doubt. Those acts a bit like what you don't want to do with ncurses. And with those, you would need to remember each line size you printed, to know where to print updates. Because, if you enlarge terminal, a print that was taking 2 lines may now occupy only 1. But with those also, a \033[A would be just "replayed" as is, even tho with new size you would want another \033[nA taking into account new line size

Some other terminals (for example the once quasi-standard xterm) just stores W×H (with H bigger than actual height, for scrolling) bytes, render printable chars and control in this virtual W×H paper, and only stores that W×H chars (with their individual attributes). For those, if you resize to a larger width, it just add blank space. If you resize to a smaller width, it just truncate what is after. And if you do the latter then the former to go back to original width, you find back the original content, but for the right part of the screen that has been blanked.

So, with xterm and the like, the only thing that matters when it comes to guess where are each printed line is "what WAS the size of the terminal when the line was printed". When for the terminals that replay the stream, what matters is "what IS the size of the terminal now"

Some others (I would say, it is the most frequent case nowadays: Terminator, iTerm, ...) do something in between. They do render the line when it is printed (for attributes and stuff), and don't "reinterpret" control chars each time the terminal needs to be rendered again (for example when resized). But the still keep track of what is printed in terms of lines, not W×H paper (a bit like a wordprocessor, that distinguish the line break explicitly typed by user from those implicitly added by wrapping). With some variants to make it more complicated. For those

resizing the terminal and the resize it back restore the content as it were. But still that means that something as simple as print("longstring\nlongstring\n\033[Axxx") then resize would not print the same thing as resizing first and print the exact same thing after. Because \033[A unit are "physical" lines. But rearrangement when resizing attach what you printed to a "logical line" (something that ends with a \n).

In other words, there is a reason why ncurses reprints everything. That is the only way. Rest is unpredictable, unless you want to code for a specific terminal. And is not even standardized and documented in files like termcap. I take that you are not excessively worried by standardization (otherwise, you wouldn't use \033 sequences, since themselves are not a universal standard. But at least those \033 you know would de facto work on any Terminal window (not in things like notebook, or some embedded terminals of some IDE tho. And not on my old ADM-5 terminal I still use)

I realize the limitations.. but I can safely assume the terminal isn't resized frequently so doing this explicit processing shouldn't be a problem. As for the type of terminal, I might have to survey and see what the users are doing (this was for a tool only a few people will be using). Thanks for all the detail.

Out of interest, I looked at docker's compose run implementation.. seems like there was a bug just as expected, when the terminal was too small to fit the entire thing on one line. i think they fixed it, so might be interesting to see how it was implemented.
